# VBA function that returns an array in excel

Tags: vba, excel

hello guys I hope you can help me with this one.
I wrote a simple function to convert returns to prices. It is useless, but I will use it explain my problem. The function works. It does what I want.

```
Function ret2prices(ByVal r As Range)

    Dim temp() As Variant
    temp = r

    Dim prices() As Variant
    ReDim prices(1 To (UBound(temp, 1) + 1), 1)
    prices(1, 1) = 1

    For i = 2 To UBound(prices, 1)
        prices(i, 1) = 1 + temp(i - 1, 1)
        prices(i, 1) = prices(i - 1, 1) * prices(i, 1)
    Next i

    ret2prices = prices

End Function
```

the problem is that when I use it in excel worksheet it always returns 0.
I would like to be able to use it the same way I use MMULT with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER. Any suggestion?

thank you very much for your time

Comment: Second dimension of `prices` should be `1 To 1`, now it's `0 To 1` and function returns array with 2 columns.

Comment: try to use your array for a range with 2 columns with CSE and you will see that @BrakNicku is right

Comment: I am sorry guys I didn't get your point

Comment: Change appropriate line to `ReDim prices(1 To (UBound(temp, 1) + 1), 1 To 1)`

Comment: Ohhh .. what an idiot ... I completely forgot that I had to specify the starting index for the second dimension too .. Now it works just fine. Thank you very much ... since we are here do you know if it is possible to refer to an entire column or row  of an array ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays in VBA are 0-based, so:

```
ReDim prices(1 To (UBound(temp, 1) + 1), 1)
```

is equivalent to

```
ReDim prices(1 To (UBound(temp, 1) + 1), 0 To 1)
```

The code in question returned expected results, but in the second column of result array. Changing lower bound of second dimension to 1 fixes the problem.

Comment: `Option Base 1` would also fix it. I general I don't like `Option Base 1`, but if all arrays in a given module are designed to transfer data between VBA and ranges, it is perhaps a valid use case.